# Replace Body but not Script within it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<body>
   <div>blabla</div>
   <div>blabla2</div>
   <script>
      ....
   </script>
</body>
```

I 'd like to replace all the content of body but leave the script tag and contents within the script tag untouched.

If I do `$('body').html('<span>hello</span>')` it'll replace the entire content so it'll look like:

```
<body>
  <span>hello</span>
</body>
```

But what I'd like is for it to look like:

```
<body>
  <span>hello</span>
  <script>...</script>
</body>
```

Basically replace everything inside body EXCEPT script. is this possible?

Comment: Better to have a `wrapper` in `body`

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for a solution without introducing any other divs..

Comment: Put your script in the `<head>`.

Comment: no script must remain in the body. long story.

Comment: @foreyez, Even after `.html()`, `script` is still running! [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/g17xzh7s/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").contents().not("script").remove();
$("<div>Test!</div>").prependTo("body");
```

Docs: [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), [`prependTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

This assumes scripts are children of the body. If they could be nested deeper, execute this first:

```
$("body * script").appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that your script is the last script in the body element (which is usually the case) you could do it like this:

```
$("body *:not(script:last)").remove();
$("body").prepend($("<div>Test!</div>"));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq43bvam/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
$('body').html('<span>hello</span><script>'+$('body script').html()+'</script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the whole html in body obviously it will remove each and every thing from it.

The best way is define the script in separate variable and then replace the body after that just append that variable in body

```
var scriptHtml = $('body').find('script');
$('body').html('<span>hello</span>');
$('body').append(scriptHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find div and remove....

```
$('body').prepend('<span>hello</span>').find("div").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remove()` method with `:not()` selector like

```js
$(document.body).find(':not(script)').remove();
// body is clear. do whatever you want.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var test1;
</script>
<span>hello</span>
<script>
  var test2;
</script>
<p>how<span>are</span>
</p><span>you</span>
```